# can not read property value of undefined in onkeypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i have input box where i have onkeypress and on kepy up functions while entering any values..so while adding my input i am getting error as Cannot read property value of undefined.

Here is my input:

```
html += '<div><input type="text" name="q'+typeInd+'[]"  onkeyup="updateQuesMark('+typeInd+','+textBoxCnt++ +',this.value)" onkeypress="return quesMarkOnly(event)" class="width-dynamic proba dva hlbox" ></div>';
```

Here is my functions:

```
 function updateQuesMark(enumCount,txtCnt,tvalue,typeFlag = null,stepCount = null,stepIdx = null)
{
  if(typeFlag == null || typeFlag == 1)
    {
      var values = $("input[name='q"+enumCount+"[]']")
      .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
      ar.Question_Format[enumCount-1].value = values.toString();
    }
    else 
    {
         var values = $("input[name='q"+enumCount+"[]']").last().val();
            // console.log(values);
         ar.Solutions[0].Steps[(stepCount - 1)].Display[stepIdx].Value = values.toString();
            // (enumCount),ar.Solutions[enumCount-1].Steps[stepCount].Display[0].Value = values.toString();
    }        
    arr = JSON.stringify(ar,undefined,2);
    $('#jasonData').html(arr);
    $('#jsonData').val(arr);
}


function quesMarkOnly(e)
{   

    evt = (e) ? e : window.event;

    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    // 8 For BackSpace, 49 For Number '1', 63 For '?', 88 For 'x', 89 For 'y', 120 For 'X', 121 For 'Y'
    if (charCode == 8 || charCode == 49 || charCode == 63 || charCode == 88 || charCode == 89 || charCode == 120 || charCode == 121 || charCode == 50 || charCode == 51 || charCode == 52 || charCode == 53 || charCode == 54 || charCode == 55 || charCode == 56 || charCode == 57) {
        console.log(e.originalTarget);
       if(e.originalTarget.value.length==1 && charCode !=8)
        {  

            console.log('1 : Return False');
            return false;
        }
        console.log('2 : Return True');
        return true;
    }
    console.log('3 : Return False');
    return false;
}
```

And i am getting error from this line

```
if(e.originalTarget.value.length==1 && charCode !=8)
```

Can any one help me where i did mistake.

Comment: `originalTarget` is only supported in Firefox. Try `target` or `currentTarget` instead, depending on your exact goal. I would also suggest passing the event to the function as an argument as `window.Event` support is also patchy - better yet use `addEventListener()` to bind your handlers.

Comment: ok 2 misn let me check

Comment: yes currentTarget is working for chrome